# best laptop for turtlebot

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Can anyone suggests me few laptop or notebook that i can look into that is able to fit with turtlebot comfortably and run smoothly with most of its applications?

I have the following notebooks in mind, any comments?

- Aspire V5-122P
- Aspire S7-191
- Asus 1015E
- Asus Vivobook X202E

Thanks
Chao

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/135191/best-laptop-for-turtlebot/) by [chao](https://answers.ros.org/users/9591/chao/) on ROS Answers with karma: 153 on 2014-03-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We needed a faster computer on a TurtleBot recently and had good results with the Dell XPS 13 Developer Edition.

---

Originally posted by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) with karma: 3248 on 2014-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chao](https://answers.ros.org/users/9591/chao/) on 2014-03-08**:
hi Ryan, will take a look at the computer. thanks :)

**Comment by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) on 2014-03-08**:
Just to specify, it's the one with Linux pre-installed.